# Error in assignment of a vector (extract from a vector of vector) to another vector with operator =

Tags: c++, c++11

I extrapolated this code of example from my real code:

```
vector<vector<unsigned short int> > v;
vector<unsigned short int> c;
vector< vector<unsigned short int> >  *suffC;
vector<unsigned short int> d;
int index =0;

c.push_back(2);
c.push_back(3);
v[0]=c;

suffC = &v;
d = suffC[index];
```

The last instruction gives me error at compile time. It is as if for the compiler the two operands (of operator =) were two different types.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: `d = (*suffC)[index];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following C's rules, C++ treats pointers in two ways:

- As pointers, by letting you apply `*` to them, and
- As arrays, by letting you apply subscript operator `[]` to them.

When you apply a subscript to a pointer `suffC`, C++ uses the second option - it treats your pointer as an array of vectors of vectors. In order to get the correct assignment, apply `*` to your pointer first, and then apply subscript. This would ensure that the custom subscript operator of `std::vector` is applied.

Note that [`\[\]` has higher precedence than `*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), so you would need to put parentheses around `*suffC`:

```
(*suffC)[...]
```

Comment: Yes, the compiler and you are right. I made a trivial mistake. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The size of v is zero on defualt, which would be compile error when we use the overload character [].